# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index while inserting data

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement, sqlexception

I am trying to insert values into a table, but it always throws "java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index". I had verified the column indexes as per my knowledge. Below is what I tried.

```
stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into test_table(ASSESMENT_YEAR,ASSESMENT_MON,CODE,KRA_CODE,BASE_VALUE,ACTUAL_VALUE,USERNAME,CHANGE_DATE)"
                + "values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,SYSDATE)");

        stmt.setInt(1, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
        stmt.setInt(2, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH));
        stmt.setString(3, getcode(dm.getStr1(), dm.getStr2())); 
        stmt.setString(4, dm.getStr4());
        stmt.setInt(5, dm.getNum1());
        stmt.setInt(6, dm.getNum2());
        stmt.setString(7, "admin");
```

The above is throwing error in the 4th stmt. But if I hardcode the values as below, data gets properly inserted.

```
        stmt.setInt(1, 2018);
        stmt.setInt(2, 12);
        stmt.setString(3, "1111"); 
        stmt.setString(4, "0000");
        stmt.setInt(5, 12);
        stmt.setInt(6, 1);
        stmt.setString(7, "admin");
```

Any help would be appriciated!!

Edit:
Below is the stacktrace

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setStringInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5386)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setString(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5374)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setString(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:282)
    at com.dao.KRADataDao.addData(KRADataDao.java:59)
    at com.service.Controller.service(Controller.java:56)
    at com.service.Dispatcher.service(Dispatcher.java:25)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:625)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1372)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The Below segment is also not working :

```
        stmt.setInt(1, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
        stmt.setInt(2, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH));
        stmt.setString(3, getcode(dm.getStr1(), dm.getStr2())); 
        stmt.setString(4, "0000");
        stmt.setInt(5, dm.getNum1());
        stmt.setInt(6, dm.getNum2());
        stmt.setString(7, "admin");
```

Comment: what error? Please add your stacktrace to your question

Comment: Could you show us the code of your class `KRADataDao`? I'm especially interested in line 59...

Comment: it seems the issue about the value you perparing , in this line         `stmt.setString(4, dm.getStr4());`
 only try to hard code it then try        `stmt.setString(4, dm.getStr4());` if this error didnt appear then check (by debuging or printing) what is the error is being passed

Comment: Same error on using below code segment : 
            stmt.setInt(1, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
            System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
            stmt.setInt(2, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH));
            stmt.setString(3, getcode(dm.getStr1(), dm.getStr2())); 
            System.out.println("KRA..."+ dm.getStr4());
            stmt.setString(4, "0000");
            stmt.setInt(5, dm.getNum1());
            stmt.setInt(6, dm.getNum2());
            stmt.setString(7, "admin");

Comment: Problem is there on this statement (line 59) :           stmt.setString(4, "0000");

Comment: Even when I hard code the value...it doesn't work

Comment: @akn the 4th column is `KRA_CODE` and it seems from its name is number, try to set int instead of setstring then try

Comment: @akn If you checked column 4 and hard code didn't work please try to hard code column 3 and tell what happens, I doubt `getcode(dm.getStr1(), dm.getStr2())` is working correctly

Comment: KRA_CODE VARCHAR2(16 BYTE)

Comment: Please show us what the class of dm looks like and what method getcode() is doing

Comment: @akn what about code what is datatype ?

Comment: @Spara yes u were right, problem is at column 3 but I am not able to find the cause of the problem as getcode() returns a string...could u plz help?          worked once only...again showing same error

Comment: If you are using an IDE just put a break point on that method and go ahead to check what does this method return?

Comment: @Spara it is showing very strange behavior...hardcoding the 3rd column worked only once...same error again

Comment: @akn maybe one of your columns is unique (like username) and you should change the value if you want to hard code again

Comment: Please show more code so we see how stmt is declared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a reuse of `stmt`. Use the try-with-resources syntax for a local instance, automatically closed, even on exception:

```
try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into test_table"
            + "(ASSESMENT_YEAR,ASSESMENT_MON,CODE,KRA_CODE,BASE_VALUE,ACTUAL_VALUE,"
            + "USERNAME,CHANGE_DATE)"
            + "values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,SYSDATE)")) {
    stmt.setInt(1, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
    stmt.setInt(2, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH));
    stmt.setString(3, getcode(dm.getStr1(), dm.getStr2())); 
    stmt.setString(4, dm.getStr4());
    stmt.setInt(5, dm.getNum1());
    stmt.setInt(6, dm.getNum2());
    stmt.setString(7, "admin");

    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

My guess is that in `getcode` the reuse of `stmt` happens.

In general always use local variables, try-with-resources. Some PreparedStatements might benefit from a longer scope, but with fixed SQL, and the name then should not be `stmt`.

Answer (score 0):

If the column does not exist, or you must enter the stmt.executeUpdate(); statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what database system you are using. 
So please verify that **CODE** is not a reserved word / keyword.

In that case please rename the third column and try again.